# filter based on the continent code PHP ip to country

Tags: php, geolocation

I have requirement in my project where i have to do a user filter based on the continent of their ip address.

i need something similar to the below function in php but only difference is i need to send the user IP address into the function and detect the continent where he is coming from and the napply some rules on criteria.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-continent-code-by-name.php

I already have a IP to country code, so at least i need to do is send the country code to the function and returns the continent. to do that i need to have a php array or some way db table that maps country to continent. I couldn't find any,

is there is any examples links or codes i can look for this to archive this functionality ?

Comment: Why don't you just use that function?

Comment: Found it in one google: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/country_continent/

Comment: that function is only for the host, not all ip i think second link could work for me

Comment: All the `geoip_XXX` functions work with either hostname or IP. When you give them a hostname, they translate it to an IP so they can look it up in the geoip database.